# Meaning of gritty, biting in a musical context

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of gritty, biting quality with regard to the sound. for example 'gritty, biting bass sound' or 'gritty, biting harmony' in a musical text?

Comment: Hello, Arash. What metaphorical senses do dictionaries give for the words? Do any seem to fit?

Comment: Perhaps the usage note ('Did You Know?') given at [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gritty) is the most relevant. Just enlarge the domain to include music as well as literature.

Comment: This question might be more appropriate on [Music.SE](https://music.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Be very aware that artistic analysis and criticism writing tends to be very non-literal. You are expected to interpret very broadly their terms. So it is very much up to interpretation. This is a good question to ask, but there may not be any good definitive answers. Also they tend to BS a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Gritty" refers to a harsh, rough, and unrefined sound.  "Biting" refers to it being strong and striking, and perhaps even accentuated.  Try to think of the real definitions of these words and think about how they could translate to musical terms.  They are not far off from their formal definitions.